# If text in a cell contains a specific word then put an image in it

Tags: javascript, html

I hope someone can help me. How can I a put an Image in a td if there is a specific word in it? Here is my code:

```
    var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
        var node = allTableCells[i];


        var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;


        if (currentText === "ArmHW")
            node.style.backgroundImage = "url('HW.png')"
```

P.S. Sorry for my english! And thank you!

Here is the complete code now... still not working =/

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var HW = new Image();
yourHW.src = "HW.png";

for (var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    if (currentText === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName")
        node.style.color = "Blue"; 
        node.style.border = "solid"

}

for (var j = 0, max = allTableCells.length; j < max; i++) {
var node = allTableCells[j];
if (Text.toString().trim() === "ArmHW") {
    node.removeChild(Text);
    node.appendChild(yourHW);
     }
```

Ok the last saved code is this one... Still doesn't work:
(Sorry for my english and lack of knowledge)

```
<script>
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");


for (var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    if (currentText === "@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName")
        node.style.color = "Blue"; 
        node.style.border = "solid";

}
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];


    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    if (currentText === "ArmHW")
        node.style.backgroundImage = "url('HW.png')"
}
</script>
```

And here is a sample of the td we are talking about:

```
       <table id="91" class="csmap">@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectCommand, Searcdb.Query(selectCommand, SearchTerm90)){<tr><td onmouseover="this.style.border='dashed'" onmouseout="this.style.border='solid'">@row.Owner<br>@row.Owner2</td></tr>}</Table>
```

---

Ok, it looks like all your code are right... Something in my page is causing disfunction... I can't put an image in the back of any td...

I'm trying to rewrite my page step by step and see where it stops. If you have any idea do not hesitate =D

---

Ok, something is missing. The code is working only if there is only one word in the td... My td's contain word
word
etc...

The script must find the good word in the td and show an image

Comment: Try `text = node.textContent.trim()` then check with `text.indexOf('ArmHW') > -1`

Comment: Your original code seen to run just fine, here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zNfLs/ are u sure image is there in the same folder as HTML?

Comment: The codes in the question lack closing `}`. Are there some messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Jukka, how can I reach the JavaScript console?

Comment: I've tryed to put your trim line... Wasn't successfull can you write how you would put it in my code shown in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

var yourImage = new Image();
yourImage.src = "HW.png";

for (var i = 0;i < allTableCells.length; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];
    if (node.textContent.trim() === "ArmHW") {
        node.textContent = "";
        node.appendChild(yourImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tryed to merge this code with my other and my tables get all messed up :/

Comment: Is there any piece of your table cells? I guess you have nested <td> where the node.textContent maybe a trouble.

Comment: The code at the top is what I got now... I've also put an example of my TDs

Comment: Shawnzhu, your script is exactly what I'm looking for... it just need to find the word in td with other words. What should I add?

Comment: This is the working script =D Thank you Shawnzhu and everyone else =D

<script>
    var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var HW = "ArmHW";
    var yourImage = new Image();
    yourImage.src = "HW.png";

    for (var i = 0; i < allTableCells.length; i++) {
        var node = allTableCells[i];
      
        if (node.textContent.match('HW')) {
            node.textContent = "";
            node.appendChild(yourImage);
        }
    }
            </script>